# How can I include a config file in a nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I would like to ask how I can inlude a configuration file in a nuget package. I have an aseembly, that needs a configuration file, and in order to make it easy to use, I want the config file to be copied during the build process of the nuget package consuming application!

I dont want to do it via a pre or post build event.

Is there any chance of doing so?